# how to know internal mechanism of join in sql

Tags: sql

I am curious if one can see the internal mechanism of merge join or any other join sql?

Comment: do you mean how the DB implements it or which algorithm the DB optimizer slected?

Comment: Turismo, Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Download some open source dbms code, and read it!

Comment: For open-source RDBMS like PostgreSQL, MySQL or SQLite you could have a look at source code. However, this might be an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle have a look at this document: [Database SQL Tuning Guide - Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL242)

Comment: This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about how they work, you can look it up [here](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/), it's a great representation of it.

If you are thinking about the code behind it, I think you'll have to work for MS to access it ;)

Comment: Mirzas, Yes. I am thinking about the code behind it.

Comment: I don't think you can access that part, unless you decompile .dll's somehow, but just reading about and looking at the logic behind it you can figure out approx. how it was coded